# Dura-Ace R9100 Bottom Bracket With A Dura-Ace FC-7900 Crankset?

Tags: shimano, crankset, bottom-bracket, hollowtech

I have just purchased a Dura-Ace FC-7900 crankset and I am trying to find a good, readily available bottom bracket to pair with it.

With Shimano's Hollowtech II and Octalink II technologies, will the Dura-Ace R9100 bottom bracket work with the 7900 cranks?

I appreciate any advice.

Cheers,
Smithy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all road Hollowtech II bottom brackets and cranks are cross-compatible.